# flutter - view not updated after updating a field in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find why my view is not updated after adding a record in Firestore.
To get the view correctly, I must go back to the previous page and then comeback again.
I have implemented SetState(){} in several places, but for now, I am not getting the result I want.

I am sure that it is a simple mistake, but I do not see it. Maybe because I am on it for too much time.  I have modified the code and try something else today, but it is not updating the listview with the new item recorded. Below, you will also find an other code that I have tried, but it is not working properly, especially as I do not have the number of documents.

Thank you for your help in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class DetailScreen_CheckList_V3 extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map listName;
  final docID;

  const DetailScreen_CheckList_V3(Map this.listName, this.docID,{
      Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State createState() => _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State(listName,docID);
}

class _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State extends State<DetailScreen_CheckList_V3> {
  Map listName;
  var docID;

  _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State(
      this.listName,
      this.docID
      );


 SetState(){
    
      listName = newItemName;
  }  

@override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     key :_scaffoldKey ,
      appBar:AppBar (
        title: Text('Your list items'),
        leading:
        InkWell(
          child:
          Icon(Icons.fast_rewind_outlined),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },),

      ),
      body:
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              /*Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 36.0, vertical: 0.0),
                height: 60,
                color: Colors.red,),*/

                Container(
                  //color:Colors.blue,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                       // Element_of_List_Badge(
                   //   color: _color,
                      //codePoint: _task.codePoint,
                      //id: _hero.codePointId,
                   // ),

                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, top:24.0),
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: 'List Name',
                        //tag: _hero.remainingTaskId,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:18.0),
                          child: Text(listName['allItems'].length.toString() + " Items",
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .body1
                                ?.copyWith(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:18.0),
                      child: Text(
                          listName['listName'].toString(),
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .title
                              ?.copyWith(color: Colors.black87)),
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: 'hello66',
                       // tag: _hero.progressId,
                        child: ElementOfAListCompletedProgressIndicator(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          //progress: model.getTaskCompletionPercent(_task),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    Container(
                    height: 550,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: listName['allItems'].length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        Map allItems = listName;

                        var checked  = allItems['allItems'][index]['itemChecked'];

                              return InkWell(
                                child: Card(
                                 child: ListTile(
                                  leading: checked == 'Yes'? Icon(
                                    Icons.check_box,
                                    color: Colors.blue,):Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
                                  title:
                                       Text((allItems['allItems'][index]['itemName'])),

                                   onTap:(){

                                    
                                    setState(() {
                                    });
                              },
                              ),

                         ));}),
                  )
                  ],
                ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){

            showAddNewItemToAList();
            setState(() {

            });
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      );
  }


  void showAddNewItemToAList() {
    TextEditingController _noteField = new TextEditingController();
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return CustomAlertDialog(
            content: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _noteField,
                    maxLines: 4,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Material(
                    elevation: 5.0,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_noteField.text != '') {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();

                          AddObjectItemToArray(_noteField.text);
                        }

                        else {
                          return;
                        }
                      },

                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 10.0, 15.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Add List',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

void showAddNewItemToAList() {
    TextEditingController _noteField = new TextEditingController();
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return CustomAlertDialog(
            content: Container(
              width: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .width / 1.3,
              height: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .height / 4,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _noteField,
                    maxLines: 4,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Material(
                    elevation: 5.0,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .width / 1.5,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_noteField.text != '') {

                          setState(() {
                            AddObjectItemToArray(_noteField.text);
                          });

                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }

                        else {
                          return;
                        }
                      },

                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 10.0, 15.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Add Item',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Future AddObjectItemToArray( newItemName,) async {

    setState(() {

    AllItems _allItems = AllItems(newItemName, 'No');

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('lists')
        .doc(docID).update({
      "allItems": FieldValue.arrayUnion([_allItems.toMap()])
    });

    setState(() {
      listName['itemName']= newItemName;
      listName['itemChecked']='No';
      print(listName);

    });
    });

  }
}
```

// another version to try

```
//encours
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gtd_official_sharped_focused/Reusable%20Widget/Dialog/custom_alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:gtd_official_sharped_focused/Views/Lists/checklist_V3/ElementOfAListCompletedProgressIndicator.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:gtd_official_sharped_focused/models_used/listItems.dart';

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class DetailScreen_CheckList_V3 extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map listName;
  final docID;

  const DetailScreen_CheckList_V3(Map this.listName, this.docID,{
    Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State createState() => _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State(listName,docID);
}

class _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State extends State<DetailScreen_CheckList_V3> {
  Map listName;
  var docID;

  _DetailScreen_CheckList_V3State(this.listName,
      this.docID);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your list items'),
        leading:
        InkWell(
          child:
          Icon(Icons.fast_rewind_outlined),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },),

      ),
      body:
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            /*Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 36.0, vertical: 0.0),
                height: 60,
                color: Colors.red,),*/

            Expanded(
              //color:Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [

                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, top: 24.0),
                    child: Hero(
                      tag: 'List Name',
                      //tag: _hero.remainingTaskId,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
                        child: Text(listName['allItems'].length.toString() +
                            " Items",
                          style: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .body1
                              ?.copyWith(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
                    child: Text(
                        listName['listName'].toString(),
                        style: Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .title
                            ?.copyWith(color: Colors.black87)),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Hero(
                      tag: 'hello66',
                      // tag: _hero.progressId,
                      child: ElementOfAListCompletedProgressIndicator(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        //progress: model.getTaskCompletionPercent(_task),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  //Originel
                  /*Container(
                    height: 550,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: listName['allItems'].length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          Map allItems = listName;

                          var checked = allItems['allItems'][index]['itemChecked'];

                          return InkWell(
                              child: Card(
                                child: ListTile(
                                  leading: checked == 'Yes' ? Icon(
                                    Icons.check_box,
                                    color: Colors.blue,) : Icon(
                                      Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
                                  title:
                                  Text(
                                      (allItems['allItems'][index]['itemName'])),

                                  onTap: () {
                                    //TODO REVOIR CODE DESSOUS NE FONCTIONNE PAS COMME JE VEUX


                                    setState(() {

                                      */
                  /* if (checked == 'Yes') {
                                        checked = 'No';

                                            */
                  /* */
                  /*.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)*/
                  /* */
                  /*

                                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                            .collection('Users')
                                            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                                            .collection('lists')
                                            .doc('lOIjBto42ZkPCs24b31J')
                                            .update({
                                          'allItems': [
                                            {'itemChecked': checked}
                                          ]
                                        }

                                       // )


                                              *//* */
                  /*  .add({
                                          'allItems': [
                                            {'itemChecked': checked}*//* */
                  /*
                                          //]
                                        );
                                      }
                                      else {
                                        checked = 'Yes';
                                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                            .collection('Users')
                                            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                                            .collection('lists')
                                            .doc('lOIjBto42ZkPCs24b31J')
                                            .update({
                                            'allItems': [
                                            {'itemChecked': checked}]
                                            }
                                        );
                                      }
                                    */
                  /*
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),

                              ));
                        }),
                  ),*/

                  //#################
                  Flexible(child:
                    StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('Users')
                          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                          .collection('lists')
                          .snapshots(),

                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> docSnapshot) {
                        if (!docSnapshot.hasData) {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                        else {
                          QuerySnapshot data = docSnapshot.requireData;
                          return Container(
                              child:
                          /*Center(child:Text(listName['allItems'].toString()))*/
                           ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: data.size , //listName['allItems'].length, //item['allItems'].length;
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            Map item = data.docs[index].data();
                            Map allItems = listName;

                            var checked = allItems['allItems'][index]['itemChecked'];
                            int nbItem = item['allItems'].length;
                            print(nbItem);
                            return Card(
                                child: ListTile(
                                leading: checked == 'Yes' ? Icon(
                                Icons.check_box,
                                color: Colors.blue,) : Icon(
                                Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
                                title:
                                    Text(item['allItems'][nbItem-1]['itemName'])
                                  /*Text(
                            (allItems['allItems'][index]['itemName'])),*/
                            ));
                          }
                          ));
                              //Text(docSnapshot.data['listName'])));
                        }
                      }),
                        ),
                        //#################
                  ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showAddNewItemToAList();
          setState(() {

          });

          (context as Element).reassemble();
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
    );
  }


  void showAddNewItemToAList() {
    TextEditingController _noteField = new TextEditingController();
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return CustomAlertDialog(
            content: Container(
              width: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .width / 1.3,
              height: MediaQuery
                  .of(context)
                  .size
                  .height / 4,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _noteField,
                    maxLines: 4,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                        const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Material(
                    elevation: 5.0,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .width / 1.5,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_noteField.text != '') {

                          setState(() {
                            AddObjectItemToArray(_noteField.text);
                          });

                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }

                        else {
                          return;
                        }
                      },

                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 10.0, 15.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Add Item',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Future AddObjectItemToArray( newItemName,) async {

    AllItems _allItems = AllItems(newItemName, 'No');

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('lists')
        .doc(docID).update({
      "allItems": FieldValue.arrayUnion([_allItems.toMap()])
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are building the list view with the listname variabke. Then added item to firebase but didn't update the value in listname and set its state.

In AddObjectItemToArray method update the listname and set its state

Comment: Thank you. I have tried, but probably not well enough. I have updated the code to show what I have done. What I have done is not working. It does not accept the SetState.

Comment: AddObjectItemToArray place this method just above the override build method.

Comment: is this correct please? ``` @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      listName = newItemName;
      
    });
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(... ``` I am getting an error Undefined name 'newItemName'. Thank you

Comment: No no i was saying above the build method
Future AddObjectItemToArray then below this @override build